# Javascript return false and event.target

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain why the clicking on `button1` doesn't get captured? I know `return false` on event `click` will stop the propagation, but it should still capture the element by `document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {console.log(e.target);});` because we are trying to capture directly the main element via `e.target` not its parent element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
       return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="button1">Button1 (dont get captured)</button>
<button id="button2">Button2 (get captured)</button>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
     console.log(e.target);});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't change that jQuery code `$("#button1").click(function(){return false});`, but still, want to capture the `button1` element when it gets clicked (with javascript), is there any workaround?

i could bind another event handler to `button1` like this `document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(e){console.log(e.target)});` in real there are many many elements which I want to capture (with different classes and id), it would be impractical to add an event listener to each of them, I showed one button just for an example. , I just simply want to log whichever element is clicked.

I can't change the jQuery code or HTML of the page, i want to run some tests in chrome console only, for which i want to capture each element which is clicked

thanks

Comment: event will not reach the document , it will stop at button only

Comment: Use the W3C DOM Event API instead of jQuery. as the Event API  lets you continue propagation while preventing the default action.

Comment: @ashishsingh thanks, could you explain it little bit more in an answer, thanks

Comment: @Dai sorry i can't use jQuery, is there any workaround with javscript?

Comment: @user9050678 what dai is suggesting is to *not* use jquery

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, oh, sorry, I can't change that jQuery code, but still, want to capture `button1` element when it was clicked with javascript, is there any workaround?, thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Try putting a log in `button1`'s click handler.

Comment: @evolutionxbox actually the actual code is much more complicated, I can't change the actual code so can't change this jQuery code `$("#button1").click(function(){return false});` and can't make any change in button tag `<button id ="button1">button1</button>`, but I want to perform some tests in Google Chrome console, so I want to capture that `button1` when it gets clicked in `chrome console` and further I want to use the tested code it in GTM (google tag manager)

Comment: `$("#button1").click(function(){
       console.log(this.id,"clicked")
    });` will add an event handler too

Comment: @mplungjan, I thought of that, but I can't use it because there are many many elements which I want to capture (with different classes and id), it would be impractical to add an event listener to each of them, I showed one `button` just for an example. , I just simply want to `log` whichever element is clicked, sry i should have mentioned that in question

Comment: `$(document).click(function(e){ console.log(e.target.id,"clicked") });`

Comment: @mplungjan `$(document).click(function(e){ console.log(e.target.id,"clicked") });` doesn't work, that is my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return false; prevents the browser from performing the default action for button1 link.

The equivalent code for `return false` is:

```
$('.button1')
   .click(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
});
```

If you just want to stop propagation use `stopPropagation()`.

Take a look at [this](http://firebreaksice.com/avoid-return-false-in-jquery-click-bindings/), and read more about [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: thanks, but I can't change the jQuery code or HTML of the page, i want to run some tests in chrome console only, for which i want to capture each element which is clicked

Comment: It's not possible, as you prevent the click event on buttton1 to take place. Definitely.

Comment: ok, thank you for the help, let's see if someone can provide any workaround

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient but worked for me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
       return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="button1">Button1 (dont get captured)</button>
<button id="button2">Button2 (get captured)</button>

  <script>
 elements = document.querySelectorAll('body *');
elements.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      console.log(e.target); // or simply console.log(elem)
});
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to everyone, especially @mplungjan who gave me this idea

Comment: You said before you can't change neither the html nor the jQuery script and now you come with a modified jQuery script. Nevertheless I don't think that you modified script works. I will test it tomorrow as it is late now and I am lying in bed.

Comment: Actually, the jQuery code written in the head cannot be changed, the javascript code written in the footer can be changed, I am not gonna use that in the footer in real, I am gonna run that in google chrome console.

Comment: Yes it works. But your question was not clear for me. A simpler solution is to add:                
$(":button").click( function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
});
to your body.